# g.gui.rlisetup configuration file missing

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin, grass-7.8

I am trying to calculate the shannon diversity index (r.li.shannon) for a landscape using the r.li tool in GRASS GIS 7.8.7. My input file is a raster of my different land covers with an assigned number for each class (similar to Corine Land Cover). I work with Windows 10.

However, it seems like I'm missing a "Configuration file" (cf. image below) which would enable me to do a "moving window" analysis (or at least, that's what I got from my QGIS (3.28.4) error message [*"Your configuration needs to be a "moving window" configuration !"*]. Or some values that I could also write up (*"ou entrer les valeurs manuellement"*) but I've got no idea what I'm supposed to write there.

[image]

I read that I should be able to find that configuration file in "C:\Users\userxy\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\r.li", however the r.li folder doesn't appear for me.

I don't find any way to open the "g.gui.rlisetup" window in GRASS 7.8.7 either, and I've looked everywhere.

I don't get what I am missing here ? Does anyone know ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2856 thank you so much for your input, this is what i was looking for !

Comment: Great, I've added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest that you do this directly in GRASS GIS. Run the `g.gui.rlisetup` module and it creates the the config file for you (based on your choice of sampling regime).  See: [the manpage](https://I%20also%20suggest%20that%20you%20do%20this%20directly%20in%20GRASS%20GIS.%20Run%20the%20g.gui.rlisetup%20module%20and%20it%20creates%20the) for details.

Comment: thank you for yor answer ! i couldn't find what you were referring to, but somebody helped me find the menu to create the configuration file so all is good.

Answer (score 0):

In GRASS (GUI) use the Raster -> Landscape patch analysis -> Set up sampling and analysis framework menu:

[image]